# Add access_token in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

In my REST server, it's requiring the access_token to be present in every request. i.e. in POSTing data, access_token needs to be submitted together with the attributes.

How do I configure backbone.js to add access_token to every GET, PUT, POST and DELETE request?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I think I found a way how to do it in jQuery.

```
$.ajaxSetup (
   {
      data: { access_token: 'my_access_token' }
   }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Backbone uses jQuery/Zepto for AJAX requests, so you can use the functionality available in those libraries.

To add custom headers to all XHR calls made by jQuery, you can use the [jQuery.ajaxSend event](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/), which is triggered before every ajax request, and modify the jqXHR it receives as an argument.

**Edit based on OP's comments:**

Probably the simplest way to modify the sent data is to override the [Backbone.sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) function. You could wrap the native implementation, and add the required property there:

```
var nativeSync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function (method, model, options) {
  //for POST/PUT requests, add access token to the request
  if(model && (method === 'create' || method === 'update')) {

    var data = _.extend(model.toJSON(), {
      access_token: 'token'
    });

    options.data = JSON.stringify(data);
  }
  //call the native Backbone.sync implementation
  nativeSync(method, model, options);
};
```

Comment: Hello fencliff. What if I want the access_token to be in the data payload itself and not on the headers, how do I achieve it? Do I $.ajaxSend(function(e, jqxhr, settings) { settings.data.access_token = 'mytoken' }) it?

Comment: That can be done as well -- but are you sure you want the access_token added to GET and DELETE requests as well? It's not typical to provide a request body using those verbs, and most web servers ignore the body anyway.

Comment: Actually I'm using the https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver REST server, and as I checked the source code they're relying on the request body.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to send a body with GET request using jQuery. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298899/how-to-send-data-in-request-body-with-a-get-when-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: Actually, the $.ajaxSend did not work for me but $.ajaxSetup worked. Those passed in the data attribute of the request for GET requests was appended to the URL as GET parameters.

Comment: Yes, jQuery does that for you. So it seems your server doesn't rely on request body for GET requests after all. By the way, looking at the answer you posted, I doubt that will work with POST/PUT request. Unless I'm mistaken, the data-property you specify in the ajaxSetup method will be overwritten with the actual request body, not extended.

Comment: Yep, sorry for that - request body shouldn't have been the term. For POST and PUT, it works since it merges the data in ajaxSetup and data in the ajax call.

Comment: Very weird. I just tested this with Backbone 0.9.1 and jQuery 1.7.2. For me the body does not merge, probably because Backbone calls `JSON.stringify` on the data before the $.ajax call. `$.ajaxSetup({data: {foo:"bar"}});`
`$.ajax({url:"/dummy", type:"POST", contentType:"application/json", data:{baz: 'qux'}});`

Gives me request body with only {baz:'qux'}. 

Glad it works anyway!

Comment: I only tested it with jQuery, now I tested it with Backbone.js and it doesn't merge now. :(

Comment: I edited my answer. It's missing error checking etc, but it should work.