# Send token with every backbone sync request

Tags: javascript, api, backbone.js, coffeescript

My PHP api requires a user token be submitted with every request from my front-end Backbone app to make sure the user...

1. Is active
2. Has permissions to access the resource

What is the easiest way to set this up in Backbone? I am guessing the only way is to overwrite Backbone.sync, but what would the code look like? CoffeeScript preferred.

### EDIT

Two more things
1. I would like to redirect the user to `/login` if I get a `403: Access Forbidden Error`
2. I pull the user model which includes the token from localStorage when the app is   bootstrapped
3. I have a baseModel and baseCollection which all models / collections come from

Comment: How does the server want the access token? In the URL, as a HTTP header, or in the request body / JSON? I've answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763280/add-access-token-in-backbone-js

Comment: generic $_REQUEST['token'] - looking at your answer, I already have $.ajaxPrefilter over-riding the base url - if I add token as a data param will that work?

Comment: I don't know what `$_REQUEST['token']` is - some PHP catchall that includes body, headers, session etc. in the same bucket I guess? If so, just add it to the `headers` object in the jQuery ajax settings. But not sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var _sync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {

    if( model && (method === 'create' || method === 'update' || method === 'patch') ) {
        options.contentType = 'application/json';
        options.data = JSON.stringify(options.attrs || model.toJSON());
    }

    _.extend( options.data, {
        "access_token": "some-token"
    });

    return _sync.call( this, method, model, options );
}
```

And just listen for the fail event of fetch/save method to redirect a user to `/login`

```
model.fetch().fail( /* redirect */ )
```

Comment: Thanks - gone with this solution for now

Comment: One question - this doesn't work for POST/UPDATE/CREATE requests...how would I get around that?

Comment: let me ask you Simon - is there a better way to authenticate a single page backbone app then sending a login token on every request

Comment: Well, that's a good way for cross-domain authentification (at least if token follow the OAuth standards). But if it's on the same domain, session cookies (or just cookies) may be easier.

Comment: is there a way to send it as part of the headers rather than in each data object?

Comment: A straight access_token not really. But via a cookie it's possible.

Comment: Hey, I came across a discussion today, and this made me think about your issue. Maybe you could use [$.ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to set defaults header containing you access token (see `headers` option of [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/))

Comment: Interesting - yea this may work - how would I collect it on the server - same way with $_POST or $_GET or $_REQUEST

Comment: I'm no PHP expert, but I think you'll have to parse the HTTP headers to get it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-get-request-headers.php

Comment: Why are you calling _.extend on a string? [since options.data might be = JSON.stringify(options.attrs || model.toJSON());]

Answer (score 19):

Backbone uses jQuery's [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), so you can use [$.ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to "set default values for future Ajax requests":

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   headers: {
     "accept": "application/json",
     "token": YOUR_TOKEN
   }
});
```

Update: an improvement to this idea (thanks to @Glen) is to use [$.ajaxSend](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) to check for the existence of a token each time before setting it in the headers of the request:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, request) {
   var token = App.getAuthToken();
   if (token) {
      request.setRequestHeader("token", token);
   }
});
```

Where App.getAuthToken() is a function in your Backbone app.

Comment: The jQuery documentation does not recommend using `$.ajaxSetup`. See here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/  The alternative would be to use `$.ajaxSend` to add the appropriate headers.

Comment: Also check out this talk on OAuth 2.0 and how they are using `$.ajaxSend` to pass the token with every request: http://youtu.be/khnmMv4_RCE?t=13m40s

Comment: `$.ajaxSend` should be changed to `$(document).ajaxSend` according to `As of jQuery 1.9, all the handlers for the jQuery global Ajax events, including those added with the .ajaxSend() method, must be attached to document.` [Link](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/)

Comment: `ajaxSend` and `ajaxSetup` should be avoided in this case in favor of an application specific solution.

Answer (score 3):

**Authentication is a responsibility of the app.**

For a Backbone app, the auth logic should be within the Backbone code and **changing the global jQuery's `ajax` behavior should be avoided at all cost.**

## Cons of `ajaxSetup` or `ajaxSend`

From the jQuery doc on [`ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/):

> **Note:** The settings specified here will affect all calls to `$.ajax` or
>   Ajax-based derivatives such as `$.get()`. This can cause undesirable
>   behavior since other callers (for example, plugins) may be expecting
>   the normal default settings. For that reason we strongly recommend
>   against using this API. Instead, set the options explicitly in the
>   call or define a simple plugin to do so.

`ajaxSend` has the same problem as mentioned above. The only advantage it has over `ajaxSetup` is calling a function each time, giving you more flexibility than the object based options passed to `ajaxSetup`.

## The safest way, the `AuthModel` and `AuthCollection`

Put the authentication logic into a base model and collection. This is the most scoped solution.

Here, you could use your already existing `BaseModel`, but I'd still favor separating the `BaseModel` from the `AuthModel` as you may want to create a custom model which uses your base model but also uses a different external API for example.

Since the new `sync` function for the model and the collection are similar but both may have a different parent implementation, I made a simple function generator.

```
/**
 * Generates a new sync function which adds the token to the request header 
 * and handles a redirect on error.
 * @param  {Function} syncFn the parent `sync` function to call.
 * @return {Function}  a new version of sync which implements the auth logic.
 */
var authSyncFunction = function(syncFn) {
    return function(method, model, options) {
        options = options || {};

        var beforeSend = options.beforeSend,
            error = options.error;

        _.extend(options, {
            // Add auth headers
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + yourTokenHere);
                if (beforeSend) return beforeSend.apply(this, arguments);
            },

            // handle unauthorized error (401)
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (error) error.call(options.context, xhr, textStatus, errorThrown);
                if (xhr.status === 401) {
                    Backbone.history.navigate('login');
                }
            }
        });

        return syncFn.call(this, method, model, options);
    };
};
```

Use the generator on both a model and a collection.

```
var AuthModel = BaseModel.extend({
    sync: authSyncFunction(BaseModel.prototype.sync)
});

var AuthCollection = BaseCollection.extend({
    sync: authSyncFunction(BaseCollection.prototype.sync)
});
```

Then you're ready to use these on models and collection you're sure will need authentication. Since you were already using a base model and collection, it would be just a matter of changing the `BaseModel.extend` to `AuthModel.extend`.

While I know you asked for a redirect on a `403 Forbidden` response, I think it should be on a `401 Unauthorized`. See [403 Forbidden vs 401 Unauthorized HTTP responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses)

## Overriding Backbone's `sync`

If you don't feel like changing all models and collections at this point, but still want to follow good practices and avoid changing the global ajax setup, overriding the `Backbone.sync` function is an easy alternative.

Using our previously defined `sync` generator:

```
Backbone.sync = authSyncFunction(Backbone.sync);
```

## Managing the local storage and the authentication

To manage the data in the local storage, check [Backbone-session](https://github.com/cofounders/backbone-session).

It's a nice implementation of a Backbone model which syncs with the local storage instead of a REST API. It also provides a nice interface to manage the authentication.

> ```
> // Extend from Session to implement your API's behaviour
> var Account = Session.extend({
>   signIn: function () {},
>   signOut: function () {},
>   getAuthStatus: function () {}
> });
>
> // Using the custom Account implementation
> var session = new Account();
> session.fetch()
>   .then(session.getAuthStatus)
>   .then(function () {
>     console.log('Logged in as %s', session.get('name'));
>   })
>   .fail(function () {
>     console.log('Not yet logged in!');
>   });
> ```

Answer (score -4):

```
Backbone.$.ajaxSetup({
   headers: { 'sid': 'blabla' }
});
```