# How to make ajax GET with parameters in http body

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.get ("/asd", {
    asd: "foo"
}, function (res){
    alert ("ok");
});
```

This sends the parameters in the querystring:

```
/asd?asd=foo
```

But I just need to use the http body to send the json object:

```
{ "asd": "foo" }
```

Comment: Body will be in POST request. Try to use jQuery.post(). But body will be in urlencoded string.

Comment: But I need to send a GET request.

Comment: I have found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298899/how-to-send-data-in-request-body-with-a-get-when-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: If it is very important you can create server side part which will take your GET request, open socket to destination site and put there GET request and converted data from GET parametrs in the body.

Comment: Ok, it seems that sending an http body with get it's not the way to go. I'll change it to post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a JSON object then you should really be using POST. However, if you absolutely need to use GET, you can do:

```
$.get ("/asd", { json: JSON.stringify({asd: "foo"}) }, function (res){
    alert ("ok");
});
```

This will convert the JSON object into a string and pass it into the `json` GET parameter (be cautious, `JSON.stringify` does not work on older browsers).