# Sending POST request with JQuery on Select box change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask

I try to send a POST request as I change the select box for my page running on local host.

Here are my codes;

This is my Flask function that shoudl respond to POST

```
@app.route('/chng_clf', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def change_clf():
    clf_name = flask.request.args.get('clf_name', '')
    print clf_name
```

This is the Jquery code doing AJAX in

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#select_clf").on("change",function() {
             $.ajax({  
                        type: "GET"
                        url: 'chng_clf',
                        data: { 
                        'clf_name': $(this).val(), 
                        },
                        success: function(msg){
                            alert('wow' + msg);
                        }
                        error: function(msg){
                            alert('wow!!' + msg);
                        }
             });
        });
    </script>
```

This is the select box in

```
<select id="select_clf">
          <option value="scene">Scene Model</option>
          <option value="object">Object Model</option>
          <option value="clothes">Clothes Model</option>
          <option value="concept">Concept Model </option>
</select>
```

However for some reason I cannot get any change after I change the select box. Could you point the problem about this code?

Comment: Maybe you need change `type: "GET"` to `type: "POST"` ?

Comment: If GET is used then data could be passed as query string parameters. For this modifications to the server method has to be taken care of for parsing those parameters.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298899/how-to-send-data-in-request-body-with-a-get-when-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: I tried both GET and POST but still same

Comment: Is the JavaScript added to the page after the `select`? If not, it runs before the `select` exists.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `cache:false` as a property on the ajax object - it might be that the browser is caching the request/response to your server

Answer (score 0):

The problem is being a noob basically. I added the `$(document).ready(function(){...});` covering my js then everything is fine now.

Comment: That's where my comment was going. Glad you figured it out.