# ASP.NET MVC Ajax function keep failing?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I would like to know why the function called by `AJAX` keeps fail in this scenario? The `FillObj()` is supposed to be called when a `dropdownlist` selection changes.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Module, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Module, new SelectList(Model.ModuleList, "Value", "Text"),
     "- Please select a Module -", new { @onchange = "FillObj()", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see I already have the `@onchange` set to `FillObj()` in the `Dropdownlist` code. However, when the selection changes, it keep goes to `alert('A error')` instead of success. The following is the `AJAX function`:

```
function FillObj() {
    var moduleID = $('#Module').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Questions/FillObjectives',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: { module: moduleID },
        success: function (objectives) {
            $("#objective").html(""); // clear before appending new list
            $.each(objectives, function (i, Obj) {
                $("#objective").append(
                    $('<option></option>').val(Obj.ObjectiveId).html(Obj.objective));
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('A error');
        }

    });
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult FillObjectives(int module)
{
    var objectives = db.Objectives.Where(o => o.ModuleId == module);
    return Json(objectives, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

Ok, I did some debugging and found out that this error message occured whenever the function is called:

[image]

Anyways to fix this?

Comment: does the controller action gets called, check using breakpoint using debugger?

Comment: and use `Url.Action` for urls like: `url: '@Url.Action("FillObjectives","Questions")'`

Comment: The controller parameter expects an integer. Try changing it to string: FillObjectives(string module)

Comment: @FernandaInesDuran that should not be a problem i think

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad In the ajax function the datatype has been defined as a json, so the type of data that you're expecting back from the server is a string. Is not correct?

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser. The code you have shown works fine. Best guess is that the code in your controller throws an exception - debug it!

Comment: And not related, but why in the world are you generating an identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` using `new SelectList(Model.ModuleList ...)` when `ModuleList` appears to be already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

Comment: I found out the error is due to DataReader command executing a query while iterating over the results from another query..I'm not really sure about fixing this though..

Comment: Start by trying `var objectives = db.Objectives.Where(o => o.ModuleId == module).Select(o => new { ObjectiveId = o.ObjectiveId, objective = 0.objective });` which will also improve greately performance. If that does not solve it, show your model for `Objective`

Answer (score 1):

**Please see edit below in EDIT 1**

If you are calling your action using `GET`, then you cannot send data in the body. You cannot do this:

```
data: { module: moduleID },
```

You can append it to the end of the url as a querystring.

```
url: '/Questions/FillObjectives?module=' + moduleID,
```

Or you can change the call to `POST` but make sure your action does not have `HttpGet` attribute applied to it.

**EDIT 1**

Thanks to the comments by  Stephen Muecke, above I said that for a `GET` operation `data { module: moduleID }` should not be done. That is half true. And since this answer was upvoted a few times, I am sharing this so other people, who are under the same impression, will know that is is not true. It will not work if whatever being posted is already a `string`. If it is not a string, jQuery will convert it to a string and append it to the URL. This is from jQuery docs:

> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests.

In the question posted, it is not already a string so jQuery will convert the data to a string and append it to the url.

Therefore, in conclusion, the code posted in this question will work but the reason it is going to error is because the code in the controller is erroring out. If you do this in the controller, it will go to success on the client side:

```
public ActionResult FillObjectives(int module)
{
     var data = new[]{ new { ObjectiveId = 1, objective = "Option 1" }, new { ObjectiveId = 2, objective = "Option 2" } };
     return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

So the issue most likely is with this line of code:

```
var objectives = db.Objectives.Where(o => o.ModuleId == module);
```

Comment: Of course `data: { module: moduleID },` works for a GET

Comment: I don't think so. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298899/how-to-send-data-in-request-body-with-a-get-when-using-jquery-ajax). Why do you say it works-i would like to know.

Comment: Your should try it first :) And refer this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Lk6qQe) to prove it

Comment: Also form the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) _Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests ....._

Comment: Hey @StephenMuecke, Thank you very much for that. I honestly was not aware of this little detail that jQuery will append it to the url. Anyways, I really appreciate you pointing this out. I edited my answer instead of simply deleting it since there are other people who are under the same impression and can hopefully benefit from it.

Comment: Actually your suggestion will also fail - OP has specified `dataType: 'json'` do in order for the test to work it would need to be `return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and so it would generate the `<option>` elements, `data` would be `var data = new[]{ new ObjectiveId = 1, objective = "Option 1" }, new { ObjectiveId = 2, objective = "Option 2" } };`